# Concat $scope.variable + idNumber ?? (from controller)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have some incremental id in elements.

```
<li class="element black" data-ng-repeat="row in rowList" >
     <span class="flecha"> 
      <i data-ng-show="actual{{$index}}" class="fa blink"></i>
      <i data-ng-show="noActual{{$index}}" class="fa fa-arrow-right color1"></i></span>
     <span class="dni">{{firmante.dni}}</span>
</li>
```

As you can imagen I can access from controller to actual0, noActual0, actual1, noActual1, actual2, no actual2... And so on, but the problem is that I don't know how much elements will be, and I cannot concat/compose the complete variable $scope.actual + 0 = $scope.actual0, which is the one I need.

PD: I have tried $scope.actual.concat(index)=true; but without success

Any help will be wellcome!

Comment: You may end up having scope update issues due to child scope (created by ng-repeat) inheritance even if you were able to do it, provided you are updating actualX within the ng-repeat. Instead as a safe bet you could create an object eg:- `$scope.actual = {}; $scope.noActual = {}` in your controller and in your view do `data-ng-show="actual[$index]"`

Comment: How about `$scope["actual" + n]` where `n` is the index?

Comment: Thank you too much! It wordked, I am very new to Angular...